# unable to execute /usr/bin/apt-get: no such file or directory when installing OpenSSH

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, virtualbox, 22.04

I am running an Ubuntu VM on virtualbox and when I enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

I get the following message:

```
unable to execute /usr/bin/apt-get: No such file or directory
```

I am trying to connect the VM to WinSCP , I downloaded the apt package and this it's in this directory:  (output of `whereis apt`)

```
apt: /usr/bin/apt /usr/lib/apt /etc/apt /usr/share/man/man8/apt.8.gz
```

I installed this version:

```
apt_2.5.3ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
```

How can I fix this??

Comment: If that is a full list of where apt-get can be found the error is correct. It is not in /usr/bin/apt-get. This must be the PATH the OS is expecting to find apt-get

Comment: @David yes sorry, I thought apt and apt-get are the same packages, I'm very new to using the ubuntu OS ,but I checked for the apt-get package entering `whereis apt-get` and this is it's path : `apt-get: /usr/bin/apt-get /usr/share/man/man8/apt-get.8.gz`

Comment: Please add the output of `grep "" /etc/*-release` to your question.

Comment: @pzkpfw I added the output to the question

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Can't you roll back to a VM snapshot before you messed up?

Answer (score 2):

You did something very reckless, and I'm puzzled as to why you did this in the first place.

You installed an unsupported version of `apt`, and you forced installation of binaries for the wrong platform (`i386`).

Since it's a VM, I would suppose you have a snapshot or something similar, so you can roll back.

Should this not be the case (?), you will have to reinstall the correct version of `apt` manually with all dependencies.

Take a look at the [package list here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/apt), for the correct version of `apt`.

For this package, and each package listed as a dependency, you should download the package manually, and then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package-file-name>
```

For a double check, do:

```
dpkg -l | grep i386
```

If there are still any `apt`-related packages left with `i386` architecture, download and reinstall those as well with the previous command.

After this is done, you should have restored the correct version of `apt` to your system.

**Tip for the future** - do not mess with any of these packages:

- `apt`, `glibc`, `python`, `systemd`
- *Any packages, where you're not completely sure of the consequences if it's messed up*

Comment: thank you for the help but I have some questions, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean that I forced the wrong installation of binaries , do you mean I need to download the apt package from the browser in the VM and from the link you attached to your answer and choose the one that matches the VM architecture ? I'm not sure about the architecture type but I think it's amd 64 bit and the terminal doesn't open when I click on it so I will try to use the failsafe terminal is this fine?

Comment: You wrote you installed `apt_2.5.3ubuntu0.1_i386.deb` - this is the `i386` version of `apt` (for Kinetic Kudu) - so you did something risky and broke the system. You can get the architecture by running `uname -i` - if it says `x86_64` it equals `amd64`. Sounds fine with the terminal - if all else fails you should probably reinstall and restore the system.

Comment: the link you provided has security concerns and Firefox on the VM forbids downloading the package. can I use wget command with a url ? if so what should I write?

Comment: `man wget` - Sorry I'm out of time today..

Comment: thanks for your help, anyway I reinstalled the Ubuntu VM again , I added the iso file in the settings of storage rather than adding it to the beginning while creating the VM , I also installed third party software . Then I installed the guest additions after updating the apt and installing linux headers. I basically wasn't installing the machine correctly. But thanks.